# What Was Before The Universe?

Tags: quran, allah, islamic-philosophy, creation, universe

I have been wondering lately what was before creation. I have come to the conclusion that before creation was God encompassing itself, there was not even nothing but God.

But I have one question to ask of this conclusion, where is the universe? Like is it contained within god?

It's just confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

We do know that Allah is uncreated and he's always been there even before the universe and will be there after.

Sunan Ibn Majah 3873 (Sahih):

> It was narrated from Abu Hurairah that :
> when going to bed, the Prophet (saas) used to say: "Allahumma Rabbas-samawati wa Rabbal-ardi, wa Rabba kulli shay'in, faliqal-habbi wan-nawa, munzilat-Tawrati wal-Injili wal-Qur'anil-'Azim. A'udhu bika min sharri kulli dabbatin Anta akhidhun binasiyatiha, Antal-Awwalu fa laysa qablaka shayun, wa Antal-Akhiru, fa laysa ba'daka shayun', Antaz-zahiru, fa laysa fawqaka shayun', wa antal-batinu fa laysa dunaka shay', aqdi 'annid-dayna waghnini minal-faqr (O Allah, Lord of the heavens and Lord of the earth and Lord of all things, Cleaver of the seed and the kernel, Revealer of the Tawrah, the Injil and the Magnificent Qur'an, I seek refuge with You from the evil of every creature You seize by the forelock. **You are the First and there is nothing before You; You are the Last and there is nothing after You**; You are the Most High (Az-Zahir) and there is nothing above You, and You are the Most Near (Al-Batin) and there is nothing nearer than You. Settle my debt for me and spare me from poverty)."

But we'll never know with certainty what was before the universe, It'll always just be speculation.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use a few examples to explain to you.
First of all picture a time machine that allows people to go back and forth in time. Now imagine raising your hands and praying to Allah. Allah can even make a time machine but will he?
Allah can send you dreams or signs in real life .These signs can work like a time machine and imagine it like a book of your record.
How you treat every other creation
of Allah is how you would be treated. In this life or combined.
Allah can answer dua at the time of your supplication. When you sleep , time may work differently.

I am reading surah Al Naml . Go to maybe verse 82 or 84 or start from the beginning and read .

Hope I gave you some indication to how the world came into being.  Also picture the shaitan or iblees relation with Allah.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).